# How can I preserve some Python object state between execution of Dask tasks?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I have a cluster of Dask workers which I want to use to parallelize prediction operations using a complex model. The model files are large and take time to load, so I have used client.run to have all workers run an initialization function to load this model.

How can I preserve Python variable state from my `client.run` function so that I can refer to it and use it in future task operations?

I found `dask.distributed.get_worker` and the [`worker.data`](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker.html#storing-data) dictionary, and have used it to set arbitrary values I'm then able to access in `map_partition` functions, but am uncertain if this is the best or safest option.

If a worker dies and is re-started, or if other workers join the cluster, is there a way to have those workers automatically call the same function I originally passed to `client.run`?

Answer (score 1):

### Just use futures

If your model/state is unchanging then I would probably just use `client.scatter` to send it out and let Dask copy it around as necessary.  This is the simplest approach and the most robust.  If a new worker arrives then it will copy it as necessary.

### Yes, using get_worker makes sense

However, if you want to manage the state yourself then yes, running a function, getting some state, and attaching it to the worker is a fine idea:

```
get_worker().my_special_state = x
```

I don't recommend placing data into `get_worker().data` because this is where Dask manages its own memory.  It might be confused to see something foreign in there that it wasn't aware of.  Things should be fine, but you never know.

### Worker plugins

> If a worker dies and is re-started, or if other workers join the cluster, is there a way to have those workers automatically call the same function I originally passed to client.run?

Yes, the simplest approach here is to use preload scripts or worker plugins.  See https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/customize-initialization.html